# onResume for android annotations

Tags: android, android-annotations

I am using android annotations and have some code that I need to execute in the onResume() function in my activity.

Is it safe to just override the onResume function from the android annotation activity (ie with @EActivity)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, you should use these lifecycle methods just like with plain Android activities. There is one thing though: [injected `View`s](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Injecting-Views)  are not yet available in your `onCreate` method, this is why [`@AfterViews`](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Injecting-Views#afterviews) exist:

```
@EActivity(R.layout.views_injected)
public class ViewsInjectedActivity extends Activity {

    @ViewById
    Button myButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // myButton is not yet available here
    }

    @AfterViews
    void setupViews() {
        // myButton is first available here
        myButton.setText("Hello");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // just as usual
    }
}
```

Comment: is it safe to assume that all injected views are available in the ```onResume``` method?

Comment: @swalkner yes. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33833912/747412) when `@AfterViews` is called.

Comment: I wasnt sure about this, but I had a clue with the documentation here: ```@AfterViews will be called everytime setContentView() is called. (Activity only)```. Then if @Afterviews is called after the content is set, it means onCreate was finished and then the next step in the lifecycle is onResume

https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/%40AfterXXX-call-order

Answer (score 2):

Yeah.  Just call `super.onResume()` and then add your code.

I'd do it just like their on create example here: https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Enhance-activities

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your custom class with lifecycle component of android. It holds life cycle information of android component so that your custom class observe lifecycle changes.

```
public class MyObserver implements LifecycleObserver {
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
    public void connectListener() {
        ...
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
    public void disconnectListener() {
        ...
    }
}

myLifecycleOwner.getLifecycle().addObserver(new MyObserver());
```