# @AfterViews is equivalent to onCreate or onPostCreate?

Tags: android, android-activity, annotations, android-annotations

About Android Annotations,

@AfterViews is equivalent to onCreate or onPostCreate?

or what is the annotation equivalent for each one?

can i remove "onCreate" and "onPostCreate" methods and put my whole code of both in the same method with @AfterViews?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In annotated `Activity`s, the `@AfterViews` annotated methods are called in `onCreate()`. In annotated `Fragment`s, the `@AfterViews` annotated methods are called in `onViewCreated()`. If you do not want to do initialization before views are created, you can safely remove your `onCreate()` method and do everything in an `@AfterView`s annotated method.
However the main reason of `AfterViews` is getting a chance to the caller to initialise injected views, which are not yet available in `onCreate()`.

Comment: that sounds cool... last question, if i declare multiples "AfterViews" there is an order of execution? i see "AfterViews" doesn't have parameters.

Comment: i mean afterviews methods will execute in order of declaration?

Comment: You should read the [wiki](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/%40AfterXXX-call-order).